# How do I store database credentials in a Config class in cases where I connect to a different database when a user logs in

Tags: php, database, class, architecture, static

I am working on a webapp where whenever it's open and the user didn't log in - the default should be set to connect to the database: `maindb`, whenever a user is logged in, the user should disconnect from the `maindb` database and get connected to his "own" database.

I tried using an if statement to check for saved `customer_host` and `customer` in the session, but PHP doesn't allow me to do such kind of thing in a class variable.

My question is:

1. How do I create such functionality that a config variable can set itself based on if the session exists. (using a call to a static variable offcourse)
2. Is this kind of structure/architecture is ok ("good practice") to my case?

   `class Config
   {`

   ```
   # Website main URL
   const WEB_URL           = 'https://potato.com/';

   # Username 
   const DB_USERNAME       = 'potato';

   # Password 
   const DB_PASSWORD       = 'disismyrealpassword';

   # Set the DB servrer 
   static $DB_HOST         = (Session::exists('customer_host')) ? Session::get('customer_host') : '127.0.0.1';

   # Set DB name 
   static $DB_NAME         = (Session::exists('customer')) ? Session::get('customer') : 'maindb';

   # Sessopm name
   static $session_name    = 'user'; 

   # token name
   static $token_name      = 'token';
   ```

PS: I am not the one that decided to create a different database for each customer and I cannot change that in my current position, so please.. try to focus on *this* problem and less about why i have a different database for each user.

This is a part of my db class:

```
private $host;

private $user;

private $password;

private $dbname;



/*************/
/*  METHODS  */
/*************/


/**
 *   Get Database instance
 *
 */
public static function getInstance()
{
    if (!isset(self::$instance)) 
        self::$instance = new Database();

    return self::$instance;
}


/**
 *   Default Constructor 
 *
 *  1. Instantiate Log class.
 *  2. Creates the parameter array.
 */
private function __construct()
{
    // Load defaults
    $this->loadDefaults();

    // INIT VARIABLES
    $this->parameters = array();                                                   

    // Connect with global vars.
    $this->Connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->dbname);
}


/**
*
*  Method to load the object with the defaut settings
*
*/
private function loadDefaults() {
    $this->user     = Config::DB_USERNAME;
    $this->password = Config::DB_PASSWORD;
    $this->host     = Config::$DB_HOST;
    $this->dbname   = Config::$DB_NAME;
}
```

If there is anything else you recommend to add, ask and I will edit.

Comment: You'd need to extend a base config class for each different environment. But why don't use INI file instead and [PHP parese_ini_file](http://php.net/parse_ini_file). Much better fit for this purpose.

Comment: @marekful i had it working with an ini file but after a research i decided it's not a good practice. I get the user data (host and dbname) from the maindb table that i'm connected to. so really, i don't need the ini file.

Comment: why don't you do this in login and logout functions

Comment: if i add it to the login function, and change the variable Config::set('customer', 'new_value') - it will work for that same page. wont it delete what i have just set if i load/redirect to a different page?

Comment: I have posted as an answer please check if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In config class

Note: after login please redirect to someothere page

```
class Config {
  static $DB_NAME_BEFORE_LOGIN         = 'maindb';
  static $DB_NAME_AFTER_LOGIN         = 'own';
  public static get_database(){
    if(logged_in){
      ///do you logic and return the database name
       self::$DB_NAME_AFTER_LOGIN;
    }else{
      //do your logic and return the database name
       self::$DB_NAME_BEFORE_LOGIN;
    }
  }
}
```

In your function

```
private function loadDefaults() {
    $this->user     = Config::DB_USERNAME;
    $this->password = Config::DB_PASSWORD;
    $this->host     = Config::$DB_HOST;
    $this->dbname   = Config::get_database();
}
```